# how to save image custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, attributes, event-observer, media-images

[image: preview in backend]

[image: preview in backend 2]

I need to display few images of product in frontend based on condition: use for virtual mirror should be checked.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Dcw\Vm\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeTemplateObserver extends \Magento\ProductVideo\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver
{
    /**
     * @param mixed $observer
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('Dcw_Vm::helper/gallery.phtml');
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="admin__field field-image-vm">
    <div class="admin__field-control">
        <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   id="use-for-vm"
                   data-role="vm-save"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"
                   value="1"
                   class="admin__control-checkbox"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][vm]"
            <% if (data.useforvm == 1) { %>checked="checked"<% } %> />

            <label for="use-for-vm" class="admin__field-label">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Use for Virutal Mirror')?>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Install script:

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Vm\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface {

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable(Gallery::GALLERY_TABLE), 'vm', [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'comment' => 'use for Vm'                ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

How to save checked images state in backend? And how to filter those images in frontend? Can you help me on this?

**UPDATE:**

following observer (on event `catalog_product_save_after`) for existing images is working, but for new images not working.

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Vm\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $request;
    protected $resource;

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource\
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $vm = array();
        $data = $this->request->getPostValue();

        if (isset($data['product']['media_gallery']['images'])) {
            $images = $data['product']['media_gallery']['images'];

            foreach ($images as $image) {
                if (isset($image['vm']) && $image['vm'] == 1) {
                    $vm[$image['value_id']] = 1;
                } else {
                    $vm[$image['value_id']] = 0;
                }
            }
   // print_r($images);exit;
            $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
            $tableName = 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery'; //gives table name with prefix
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();

            if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])) {
                foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image) {
                    if (isset($vm[$image['value_id']])) {
                        //Update Data into table
                        $sql = "Update " . $tableName . " Set vm = " . $vm[$image['value_id']] . " where value_id = " . $image['value_id'];
                        $connection->query($sql);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which event you observe? I will try to reproduce it and to check why it's not working.

Comment: catalog_product_save_after,if image is new value id will be null,so first time not working.

Comment: And which event you are using for the `ChangeTemplateObserver`?

Comment: <preference for="Magento\ProductVideo\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver" type="Dcw\Vm\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver" />

Comment: Does my answer helped you?

Comment: @siarhey yes,already marked as correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your observer there is a lot of unnecessary code. You can change it like:

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Vm\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $request;
    protected $resource;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource\
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $this->request->getPostValue();

        if (isset($data['product']['media_gallery']['images'])) {
            // print_r($images);exit;
            $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
            $tableName = 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery'; //gives table name with prefix
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();

            if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])) {
                foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image) {
                        //Update Data into table
                    $vmValue = !empty($image['vm']) ? (int)$image['vm'] : 0;
                        $sql = "UPDATE " . $tableName . " SET vm = " . $vmValue . " WHERE value_id = " . $image['value_id'];
                        $connection->query($sql);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Because you don't need to store data from a request, as it has no `value_id` in newly created images, therefore your data didn't remain when adding the new image.

To get data in other places I wrote a plugin. It's adding the column `vm` to media gallery select:

> app/code/Dcw/Vm/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery">
        <plugin name="afterCreateBatchBaseSelect" type="Dcw\Vm\Plugin\Product\Gallery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Code:

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Vm\Plugin\Product;

class Gallery
{
    public function afterCreateBatchBaseSelect(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select
    ) {
        $select->columns('vm');

        return $select;
    }
}
```

So now your custom attribute `vm` should always exists in the products media data.

To hide the vm-images on the frontend you can write plugin:

> app/code/Dcw/Vm/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="afterGetMediaGalleryImages" type="Dcw\Vm\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Code:

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Vm\Plugin;

class Product
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetMediaGalleryImages(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        foreach ($result as $key => $image) {
            if ($image['vm']) {
                $result->removeItemByKey($key);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

To obtain the vm-images from the product, use code writen by @Marius (without a plugin that deletes this images):

> ```
> $images = []; 
> foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
>     if ($image->getVm()) {
>         $images[] = $image;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @SivaKumarKoduru I'm glad to help you

Comment: Hello, @Siarhey Uchukhlebau I have to Implement your code at backend side.but when I upload multiple images then I got only one image data with VM, Like this actually I need all images selected value into post data.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks for this i think i'm nearly there: attributes save for me however the values are not showing in product edit form? Wondering if you have time you could see what I did wrong? The question mentions data.useforvm to pull values however that doesn't seem referenced anywhere, is there a step i'm missing? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301685/add-an-attribute-to-product-image-detail-in-admin-form-media-gallery-attribute

Comment: I saved the new field to a column in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value table. $product->getColumn() is not working. Do you know how can I make that work?

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving in frontend:

Let's say that the product for which you want to display the virtual mirror is `$product`.
You can get the images that are marked with your custom attribute like this:

```
$images = []; 
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    if ($image->getVm()) {
        $images[] = $image;
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through the `$images` array and display them where you need.

To save the value of that checkbox in the backend I think you need to write an `after` plugin for the method `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media\ImageEntryConverter::convertFrom` where you attach the value you get from post in the `$entryArray`.

Comment: in $image there is no property with vm, but in db that field existed.so its returning empty array.

Comment: Ok. I'll dig further.

Comment: any help on this,really its something difficult managing js in magento2.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find anything useful. I will try to see if I can get something after work.