# How to save image custom attribute in magento

Tags: magento2

[how to save image custom attribute in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178030/how-to-save-image-custom-attribute-in-magento-2)

I'm a newbie. I have trying to follow this ticket but the file **ProductSaveAfter.php** don't work. And has an warning:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\hebes2\app\code\MGS\Mpanel\Plugin\Product.php on line
>   14

Please help me!

Dcw\Vm\Observer\ProductSaveAfter.php :

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Vm\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $request;
    protected $resource;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource\
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        print_r($this->request->getPostValue());exit;
        $data = $this->request->getPostValue();

        if (isset($data['product']['media_gallery']['images'])) {
            // print_r($images);exit;
            $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
            $tableName = 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery'; //gives table name with prefix
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();

            if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])) {
                foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image) {
                    //Update Data into table
                    $vmValue = !empty($image['vm']) ? (int)$image['vm'] : 0;
                        $sql = "UPDATE " . $tableName . " SET vm = " . $vmValue . " WHERE value_id = " . $image['value_id'];
                        $connection->query($sql);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Dcw\Vm\Plugin\Product.php :

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Vm\Plugin;

class Product
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetMediaGalleryImages(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        foreach ($result as $key => $image) {
            if ($image['vm']) {
                $result->removeItemByKey($key);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Dcw\Vm\Plugin\Product\Gallery.php :

```
namespace Dwc\Vm\Plugin\Product;

class Gallery
{
    public function afterCreateBatchBaseSelect(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select
    ) {
        $select->columns('vm');

        return $select;
    }
}
```

Dcw\Vm\etc\di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\ProductVideo\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver" type="Dcw\Vm\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver" />
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery">
        <plugin name="afterCreateBatchBaseSelect" type="Dcw\Vm\Plugin\Product\Gallery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Dcw\Vm\etc\frontend\di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="afterGetMediaGalleryImages" type="Dcw\Vm\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code here?

Comment: Hi Dharmendra, I updated my code