# Assign Image Role to Multiple Products Images

Tags: magento2, product-images, custom-options

I have added image role by using this code

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'attribute_image_code',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Image Attribute Name (Label)',
                'input' => 'media_image',
                'frontend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'filterable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Now I want to assign this role to multiple images but it only works for one Is there any way to assign it to multiple images .. ORRRR How can I add an option like **Hide from Product Page** checkbox

Comment: Did you found the solution for this

Comment: @SheshgiriAnvekar [Hope This May Help You](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178030/how-to-save-image-custom-attribute-in-magento-2)